# Interpretation of Multiplicity of a relation

Tags: uml, associations, relation

I'm struggling to understand the multiplicity of a relation.

In general how should one interpret this

[image: general]

is this every entity of type P has between a and b entities of type C or between x and y or something else. All explanations I've found so for only adres the cases a,x = 0,1 and b,y = *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's vice versa. `P` has `x..y` entities of type `C` in access and `C` has `a..b` of `P`.

As a side note: the multiplicity labels should not be placed to hide parts of the association.

Answer (score 1):

Every Association contains two independent statements:

- **Every** instance of P is linked to x..y instances of C
- **Every** instance of C is linked to a..b instances of P

Being linked could mean, that P or C have an attribute of type C or P. This is the most common incarnation of a link, but UML does not prescribe this.